# Sizes and Timeouts on streaming service contract in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, streaming, wcf-binding

I am currently working on a small project, where I need to send a potentially large file over the internet.

After some debating I decided to go with the streaming option instead of a chunking approach. The files can potentially be very big, I don't really want to specify an exact upper bound, 2GB maybe 4GB, who knows.

Naturally this can take a long time. Again I don't really want to have a timeout. It just takes as long as it takes, doesn't matter.

While poking around trying different files of varying size, I slowly, step by step, tuned the properties of my BasicHttpBinding. I am just wondering if the values I came up with are basically okay, or if they are totally evil?

```
transferMode="Streamed"
sendTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807"
receiveTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807"
openTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807"
closeTimeout="10675199.02:48:05.4775807"
maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807"
```

This just doesn't feel right somehow, these are just the maximum possible values for each underlying data structure. But I don't know what else to do.

So again:

Is this basically the right approach? Or did I completely misunderstand and misuse the framework here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, a more natural approach might be to send the file in a sequence in mid-size chunks, with a final message to commit; this also makes it possible to resume from error. There is perhaps a slight DOS issue with fully open numbers...

Answer (score 0):

I already have a problem with streaming when the connection between WCF client and server goes through the VPN. If interested, read more in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/a8c6811f-f80e-4484-b33b-b22dd48c1c3c).

If the stream is big enough to be streamed for more then a minute - an exception occurs.